# How can I modify TimThumb script to give my post thumbnail an auto height?

Tags: php, wordpress, image, timthumb

I'm having an issue with the featured images that are being generated (cropped and resized) by the TimThumb script.

Is there a way to tell the script that I want the images to be a specific width (with no cropping) and then have an auto height to retain the correct proportion?

Here is a link to the site I'm referring to: http://aquariuscocktail.com

If you scroll down a bit you will see a post by the name of "Baby Blues" with a picture underneath. That picture is getting cropped and blown up larger because of TimThumb and I can't seem to figure out why or how.

Here is the URL it's generating:

```
http://aquariuscocktail.com/wp-content/themes/writer-parent/framework/timthumb/timthumb.php?src=http%3A%2F%2Faquariuscocktail.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2013%2F11%2Ftester.jpg&h=670&w=670&zc=1&q=100
```

The original dimensions of the uploaded image are 670 x 476

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Patrick

Comment: Did you get this working? Check my answer, if you still need help contact me http://bit.ly/UHR2WS

Answer (score 0):

You can do away with timthumb and use the built in functions of WordPress to display images on your home page sized correctly. This reduces load on your server and can help prevent malware if your version or future versions of timthumb become vulnerable to XSS

Add a new image size to your site `add_image_size( 'home-post-featured', 670, 9999, false );`

Use Regenerate Thumbnails, then replace the timthumb code in your template to use `the_post_thumbnail()`

** EDIT **
Another problem is this image http://aquariuscocktail.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/AQC-shop-538x1024.png is not 670 wide, so distortion is coming from the width stretching as well as the height. Make sure you are uploading images 640 wide and you use the full size image.